# Run postconstruct annotated method when remote rest api is changed

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-batch

I have static data rest api which I am calling in my microservice when app starts by annotating @postconstruct and caching the data from this api

Now, I want to refresh the cache whenever static data api is modified means it should call @postconstruct method again

How can I achieve this in spring boot, microservices?
I heard of steps cope but not sure how to use that

Any reference code link or approach would be helpful

Comment: is this postconstruct  is from spring?

Comment: step scope is Spring Batch specific... Why your `@PostConstruct` annotated method cannot be invoked explicitly... just get hold of that class when you refresh the cached data and call the method

Comment: I am calling loadStaticData in @postconstruct annotated method. How do I configure to refresh the cached data when remote api data changes?

Comment: When should the method annotated with @postconstruct be called? Is there a trigger or specific point in time?

Comment: I call it during startup but it should be called whenever remote api that I am caching changes its data.

Comment: So either the remote api has to notify your service about changes. During this notification, you can invoke the method annotated with @postconstruct again. Or you have to check for updates in a specified time interval and invoke the method if necessary.

Comment: kedenk, can I leverage any spring feature to achieve this?